# Java string convert to Date

Tags: java, string, date

I need to change this format to Date

```
Fri Oct 28 05:47:54 SGT 2011
```

I not sure the SGT how to set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all patterns in [the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). `SGT` is a general time zone and it's listed as `z`. So, the pattern should look like:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

The month names seems to be English, so this should do in combination with [`Locale.ENGLISH`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = sdf.parse(string);
// ...
```

Interesting enough, that's also basically the default pattern of [the `Date#toString()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) (which you would see when you're doing a `System.out.println(date)`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DateFormat class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), specifically the `parse` method.